# Converting celsius to fahrenheit using program parameter

Tags: c

"For this program, I want to use program parameter to collect user data. For example, you can compile with `program -c 20` which will convert 20 to Celsius, and when compile with `program -f 20`, the program will convert 20 to fahrenheit. The program can only accept `argv[0]` as `-c` or `-f`, and `argv[1]` will be converted to floating point. Below is my program, I get some warnings and errors. Can you help me to get it right.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

    const char* c = "-c";
    const char* f = "-f";

    float temp_c;


    if(0==strcmp(argv[1],c))
    { 
      sscanf(s,"%f",&temp_c);
      temp_c =  (argv[2]-32)*5/9;
      printf("%f celsius = %f fahrenheit", &temp_c, argv[2]);


    }else if(f0==strcmp(argv[1],f)){

 sscanf(s,"%f",&temp_c);
 temp_c =  argv[1]*9/5+32;
 printf("%f celsius = %f fahrenheit", &temp_c, argv[2]);

    }else

    {
      printf("please use correct flag");
      exit(0);
    }
 }
```

Comment: argv[0] is not what you think it is, for one thing.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to tell us what the warnings and errors are instead of making us compile it mentally. Just a thought....

Comment: Are you sure you mean "compile with" and not "run with"? Also, `argv[0]` is traditionally the name of your program... so it would never be `-f` or `-c` unless you named your program that way... also you can't assign a string literal to a `char`.

Comment: ..and you cannot compare strings with '==', even if you declare them as the correct type.

Comment: Also, when you have gotten the pointers and arrays sorted out, please check any other of the millions upon millions of questions on the topic "I'm a beginner and my fahrenheit/celsius converter gives me the wrong answer", that you will find all over the net.

Answer (score 2):

```
char c = "-c";
char f = "-f;
```

This is a problem. `""` means `string`  but you are declaring these variables as `char`

Use,

```
char c[] = "-c";
char f[] = "-f";
```

then compare them using `strcmp(argv[1], c)`.

Comment: how can i fix that, and make the program work?

Comment: edited my answer to solve your problem. watch that

Comment: I have fixed the program as above, but error still happened

Comment: what errors are you watchng? can you specify? Post error message and your new code here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mistake (and implementation defined behaviour):

```
char c = "-c";
char f = "-f"; /* Note I added missing closing "/ */
```

change to:

```
const char* c = "-c";
const char* f = "-f";
```

`argv[0]` is name of the program. The first argument is stored in `argv[1]`. You cannot use `==` to compare the content of strings in C (`==` compares the base addresses of arrays in which the strings are stored), so this is incorrect:

```
if(argv[0] == c)
```

change to:

```
if (0 == strcmp(argv[1], c))
```

same for `else if` condition.

Use `scanf()`, not `sscanf()`, to retrieve the user input (`s` is undefined btw) and check its return value to ensure the variable was assigned a value:

```
if (1 == scanf("%f", &temp_c))
```

Final calculation is incorrect:

```
temp_c =  (argv[1]-32)*5/9
```

change to:

```
temp_c =  (temp_c-32)*5/9
```

same for other calculation.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  
   const char* c = "-c";
   const char* f = "-f";
   
   float temp_c;
   
   
   if(0==strcmp(argv[1],c))
   { 
     sscanf(s,"%f",&temp_c);
     temp_c =  (argv[2]-32)*5/9;
     printf("%f celsius = %f fahrenheit", &temp_c, argv[2]);
     
   
   }else if(f0==strcmp(argv[1],f)){
     
     sscanf(s,"%f",&temp_c);
     temp_c =  argv[1]*9/5+32;
     printf("%f celsius = %f fahrenheit", &temp_c, argv[2]);
     
   }else
     
   {
     printf("please use correct flag");
     exit(0);
   }
   

}

Comment: I just fixed my program, but still getting errors

Comment: @StevenLiu, you should not update the question in repsonse to answers. This appears to make answers irrelevant and will confuse people coming to the question later. However, this is a mistake: `(argv[2]-32)*5/9;` You need to convert `argv[2]` to arithemtic type.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = "-c";
char f = "-f;
```

is wrong. These are not chars, but strings, so store them as `char *`. And strings must be balanced. (The latter error you could have found yourself.)

```
if(argv[0] == c)
```

Here you want

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], c) == 0)
```

as `argv[0]` is the name of the program and strings cannot be compared with `==`.

```
sscanf(s,"%f",&temp_c);
```

What is `s`?

```
temp_c =  (argv[1]-32)*5/9;
```

No. You are mixing up pointer and float arithmetics.

```
}else if(argv([0]=f){
```

See above. BTW: This should give a syntax error from the compiler; easy to spot by yourself.

```
sscanf(s,"%f",&temp_c);
```

See above.

```
temp_c =  argv[1]*9/5+32;
```

See above.

Comment: Lesson learnt: you cannot _guess_ programming. You must actually _know_ programming, you must know what every single line of your program does, or it will simply not work. Or worse: it may appear to work but contain latent bugs.

Answer (score 1):

As of revision 3 of your code:

```
mike@linux-4puc:~> gcc a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:29:16: error: ‘s’ undeclared (first use in this function)
a.c:29:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
a.c:30:30: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘char *’ and ‘int’)
a.c:33:9: error: ‘f0’ undeclared (first use in this function)
a.c:35:20: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘char *’ and ‘int’)
a.c:40:8: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
```

So let's go through them:

1) Yup, here you use `s` and it has not been declared anywhere. Read up about `sscanf` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/). The first parameter is a `const char *`, or a string where we'll find the content. In your case `s` is not declared. You want to get the temp (or second command line variable) so you need to pass `argv[2]` here, not `s`

```
sscanf(s,"%f",&temp_c);   -->  sscanf(argv[2], "%f", &temp_c);
```

2) Again, you're using something that has not been declared, this time `f0`.

```
else if(f0==strcmp(argv[1],f)){
```

Looks like you just wanted 0 like in the first `if`, so just remove the `f`

3) `Invalid operands to binary *` means you're trying to do math on a string and the compiler doesn't know what to do. The arguments, `argv[x]`, are strings no matter if you pass numbers or not so this:

```
temp_c =  argv[1]*9/5+32;
```

Is not valid. You **already** did the conversion too! That's what the `sscanf()` did for you, so the value you want is `temp_c`, not `argv[1]`

4) `incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function` in this case means that you're trying to use a standard function `exit()` but didn't include the correct header file. Including `<stdlib.h>` will fix that.

---

That takes care of the warnings and errors.. however your code still has some logic and conformance problems:

```
printf("%f celsius = %f fahrenheit", &temp_c, argv[2]);
```

This is not what you want. Don't pass the address of `temp_c`, you want the value, not the value of the pointer. Read up on the ampersand in C, you can't just throw these around wherever you want to.

The second issue with this statement is argv[2] is not a number, it's a string (we went over this before) so you have to use the string format specificer `%s` not the float `%f`.
Same issues in both your `printf`'s.

One more issue, your `main` function should return an `int`, that's what `int main(...` means. Before you leave the function you should make sure there's a `return 0;` or `exit(0);` You have one, but only if you fall into the `else` case. You should just have one, unconditionally, at the end of the function.